# What is this bird symbol called by the AriZal

Tags: practical-kabbalah

[image]

It says it's a kamia that's frequently attributed to the Arizal but this drawing was by Rabbi Eliezer of Worms and Rabbi Eliyahu Baal Shem.

I've seen this drawing in the 1855 Lemberg Sha'ar Hayichudim by Rabbi Chaim Vital.

What is this bird called?

Comment: It doesn’t say the *drawing* per se is from the above mentioned names; the heading says the *names* are.

Comment: I prefer not to write an answer to this,but check out the book Hebrew Magic Amulets by T.Schrire. In that book he describes all those Shemos that appear on this kameah. The picture of that bird is also mentioned in the book ,ayin sham.